# How do I make a function start working at a certain time and at a certain interval?

Tags: python, schedule

I'm trying to make the function print1 start the function print2 (which will run every 30 min)
But I can't stop this process at a certain time.
The function keeps running.
I need my function (e.g. print1) to run every day at 6 am. And make calculations at intervals of 30 minutes. And end at 10 pm. And the next day all over again.

```
import schedule
from schedule import every, repeat, run_pending


def print2():
    print(" interval 30 sec")
    # return schedule.CancelJob


def print1():
    schedule.every(30).minutes.do(print2)
    print("run")
    return schedule.CancelJob


schedule.every().day.at('6:00').do(print1)
job = schedule.every().day.at('10:00').do(print1)
schedule.cancel_job(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below creates a job to run every day at 6:00 which creates a repeating job then stops at 10:00. The primary 6:00 job will run every day. To work, need to add a loop to main and call `schedule.run_pending()`.

**Example #1**

```python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import schedule
import time

class Job:

    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False
        self.job = None

    def print2(self):
        if debug:
            print(">> interval 1 sec")
        else:
            print(">> interval 30 mins")

    def print1(self):
        print("started")
        self.running = True
        if debug:
            self.job = schedule.every(1).seconds.do(self.print2)
            stop = (datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=30)).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print("Stop at:", stop)
            schedule.every().day.at(stop).do(self.cancel)
        else:
            self.job = schedule.every(30).minutes.do(self.print2)
            schedule.every().day.at('10:00').do(self.cancel)

    def cancel(self):
        print("cancel job")
        schedule.cancel_job(self.job)
        print("Stopped at ", datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        self.running = False
        return schedule.CancelJob

# main

# debug = True runs 10 seconds from now then stops repeating job after 30 seconds
# set debug = False to run at 6:00 and stop at 10:00
debug = True

job = Job()

if debug:
    now = datetime.now()
    start = now + timedelta(seconds=10)
    start = start.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("current:", now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    print("start:  ", start)
    schedule.every().day.at(start).do(job.print1)
else:
    schedule.every().day.at('6:00').do(job.print1)

while True:
    if not job.running:
        print("waiting")
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Output:**

```
current: 10:29:38
start:   10:29:48
waiting
waiting ... printed 10x
started
Stop at: 10:30:18
>> interval 1 sec
>> interval 1 sec ... print 30x
cancel job
>> interval 1 sec
Stopped at  10:30:18
waiting
waiting
...
```

Instead of using schedule to start and stop jobs, another approach schedules a single job to run every day. When the scheduled job is activated, it kicks off a new Thread that executes a function at set interval then stops running at a particular time.

**Example #2**

```python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import schedule
import time
from threading import Thread

class Job:

    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False

    def print2(self):
        if debug:
            print(">> interval 1 sec")
        else:
            print(">> interval 30 mins")
        # do something

    def check_job(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        if debug:
            stop = now + timedelta(seconds=10)
            sleep_time = 1  # every 1 second
        else:
            # stop at 10am
            stop = now.replace(hour=10, minute=0, second=0)
            sleep_time = 600  # every 10 minutes
        print("Stop at:", stop.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        while True:
            # perform the periodic function to do something
            self.print2()
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            if datetime.now() >= stop:
                print("Stopped at ", datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
                self.running = False
                break

    def print1(self):
        print("started")
        self.running = True
        # create and start a new Thread that runs check_job() function
        t = Thread(target=self.check_job, daemon=True)
        t.start()

# uses same main as example #1 above
```

Comment: You must have misunderstood me. I need my function (e.g. print1) to run every day at 6 am. And make calculations at intervals of 30 minutes. And end at 10 pm. And the next day all over again.

Comment: You want to start the every 30 minute calcs at 6am and continue until 10pm. Updated example to do that.